# Passing a math formula to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I write a formula in a function and pass it to my EF query. It does not work. But functions like Math.Pow(x,x) works. Why? Do I have to integrate my formula directly in my queries?

```
var i = from u in Locations
    where (SquareRoot(u.SomeField) < radius)
    select u;

    public double SquareRoot(double val)
    {
    return Math.Pow(val, 0.5);
    }
```

But this works:

```
var i = from u in Locations
    where (Math.Pow(u.SomeField, 0.5) < radius)
    select u;
```

The actual formulas I want to use will be much larger than a simple square. Formulas such as distance between points on earth, etc. This is why I'd love to break out my formulas from the query and use them as functions.

The actual formula looks like this:

```
public double DistanceBetweenPoints(double centerLat, double centerLon, double pointLat, double pointLon)
{
    const double sphericalValue = 69.1;
    return Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(sphericalValue*(pointLat-centerLat), 2)) + (Math.Pow(sphericalValue*(pointLon-centerLon)*Math.Cos(centerLat/57.3), 2)));
}
```

Math.Sqrt() and Math.Cos is not supported by EF.

Comment: Can you help me out here? Is `Math.Pow(u.Latitude, 0.5)` actually meaningful?

Comment: I simplified the formula, But the problem I ran into was `Math.Sqrt` is not supported. That is the same as SquareRoot.

Comment: I know that, I'm was just surprised that square root of latitude was something meaningful, especially when compared to radius, but it appears you were just making up an example, not using something actual, which is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the framework can't figure out how to translate your method to SQL. You're asking too much of the framework to be able to do that. When the query provider encounters a call to one of your methods in the expression tree (`Expression.Call`), it notes the method being called is not one that it knows how to parse and pukes accordingly.

However, the query provided does know how to translate `Math.Pow` to `POWER` because it was designed that way.

It really is that simple.

Comment: So integrate any formula I'm going to use inside the queries? thats the only way?

Comment: @Shawn Mclean: You could try a user-defined function on the server and pull it into your model via EF. (I have never done this, as I frown on business logic on the server but it is an option.)